# live reload running but ionic serve dont

Tags: ionic-framework

I am a newbie in ionic framework. I have installed all features to use ionic box (shown in http://therockncoder.blogspot.com.br/2014/10/getting-started-building-mobile-apps.html), but my ionic serve is not running.

Below I show the browser with the error:

[image]

And here my command, showing that the live reload is working. I change anything in my index.html, and a message telling that the website was changed, is showed.

[image]

Here is my index.html file, without any change:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>

      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

I did those steps, after have installed everything:

- vagrant ssl
- cd /projects (my projects folder has this name)
- ionic start PROJECT_NAME_HERE tabs
- cd PROJECT_NAME
- ionic serve

I have also tried the steps:

- vagrant ssl
- cd /projects (my projects folder has this name)
- ionic start PROJECT_NAME_HERE tabs
- cd PROJECT_NAME
- ionic platform add android
- ionic serve

And I have also tried the command 'ionic address' to change between the 2 url  options ( localhost and an Ip address ). The same problem in both of them.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried that : http://localhost:8100/#/

Comment: Are you using the latest version of ionic? You can check by entering: `ionic -v` in you cmd. If not update with: `npm install -g ionic` and update the ionic lib in your project by executing `ionic lib update` in the root directory of your project.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

ionic serve --address 0.0.0.0

Comment: What does this do?? And why?